# error while using subquery in insert operator

Tags: sql-server, database, insertion

I have table with the following structure:

```
FirstName|MiddleName|PatientID
```

I want in other table to store all distinct FirstNames. I have Created table named TBL and I want to insert into it all distinct `FirstName` rows. Let's assume first table name uis `TBL1`. I tried the following:

```
INSERT Into TBL(FirstName) VALUES (SELECT DISTINCT FirstName FROM TBL1)
```

But I've got error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, ! =, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What am I missing here? I am talking about Microsoft Sql Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
INSERT Into TBL(FirstName) 
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName FROM TBL1
```

`VALUES` is for the values in a *single* row.